# Replace 2 double quotes with 1 double quote with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, xslt, replace, double-quotes

I have a TNT XML request that I am sending from a Microsoft Access 2003 database to their XML API server to retrieve a label.  The response that is sent back to me must be translated with XSLT. The problem is that the response that I receive contains two double quotes for each quoted phrase instead of one.  I need to modify the HTML so that it displays normally, with one double quote on either side.

Just to give an example of what this looks like:

```
<META http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html"">
<title>TNT Label</title><script type=""text/javascript"">

                        if (firstPagePrinted) {
                            document.writeln('<div class=""pagebreak"">');
                            document.writeln('<font size=""1"" color=""#FFFFFF"">.</font>');
```

I have tried using replace() many times in all kinds of variations. I've used the ASCII Chr(34) representation of ", as well as Unicode CHrW(&H22).  These are just a few examples of my unsuccessful attempts to solve this problem:

```
Replace(strResult, Chr(34), ChrW(&H22))
Replace(strResult, """", ChrW(&H22))
Replace(strResult, """", "")
```

This is the code I am using to transform and save the XML document:

```
Dim strResponse, strDisplayString, strSQL, desktopPath As String
Dim sTNTXML, sResponseXML, nodeList, strResult

Dim objRequest As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
objRequest.Open "POST", "https://iConnection.tnt.com/ShipperGate2.asp", False, "", ""
objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "ShipperGate_socket/1.0"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "Host", "iConnection.tnt.com"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", CStr(Len(sTNTXML)) + 7

DoCmd.Hourglass True
objRequest.send "xml_in=GET_LABEL:" & modTNTShipping.completeNum
sResponseXML = objRequest.responseText
DoCmd.Hourglass False

Dim mydoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
mydoc.async = False
mydoc.loadXML (sResponseXML)

Dim stylesheet As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
stylesheet.async = False
stylesheet.Load "http://iconnection.tnt.com:81/Shipper/NewStyleSheets/label.xsl"

Dim result As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
result.async = False

strResult = mydoc.transformNode(stylesheet)

Dim strQuote As String
strResult = Replace(strResult, Chr(34), ChrW(&H22))

Open "C:\users\chris\desktop\TNTLabel.html" For Output As #1
Write #1, strResult
Close #1
```

If there is anything somebody could suggest to alleviate this issue (even if it doesn't use Replace()), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try `Replace(strResult, Chr(34)&Chr(34), Chr(34))`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that already unfortunately, although that is a good idea.

Comment: Doubling up the `"` is an escape, inside a string literal. I think you might actually need this...

Comment: @SethCohen that replaces the single quotes. How does that help?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308060 they have 39 called a "single straight quote" which prints as " in the article and 34 as "apostrophe" which prints as ' instead of ", so that seemed weird so I thought you might give 39 a try

Comment: Interesting... I think they have those numeric vals flipped, or, at least they are not congruent with VBA where `Debug.Print CHR(34)` will display `"` and `Debug.Print Chr(39)` displays `'`.

Comment: Perhaps replacing like this will work? `Write #1, Replace(strResult, Chr(34), Chr(39))`. Appears to produce well-formed HTML as long as you don't need to escape any quotes...

Comment: How did you ascertain that the quotes are doubled? If you're looking at the value in a debugger, the quotes might already be correct and just showing up as double in the debugger. Have you tried passing the value into your XSLT?

Comment: Thanks for all the input, everyone.  I really appreciate it.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, maybe, using `FileSystemObject` to create the text file/html file:

```
Public Const strResult As String = "<META http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html"">" '"document.writeln('<div class=""pagebreak"">');"
Sub Test()
Dim sFile As String
Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject

sFile = "C:\users\" & Environ("username") & "\desktop\TNTLabel.html"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile(Filename:=sFile, Overwrite:=True).Write strResult

Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

This creates the following text file, note that there are no double-quotes and I did not use any `Replace` or other string functions to remove them from the `strResult`:

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, when I used freefile method to write the file, it preserves it as string literal, where the double-quotes are required as an escape character.  I am still not sure that you should be "replacing" or removing these, since this is an HTML file which includes script/javascript, so you have string script inside a string HTML.  In my *very* limited web/HTML experience, this might actually be necessary to properly escape the characters, or as JLRishe suggests, perhaps this *is* correct for XSLT.

```
Open "C:\users\chris\desktop\TNTLabel.html" For Output As #1
Write #1, strResult
Close #1
```

Comment: I'll take a look at using FSO, @DavidZemens.  In regards to your suspicions about two double quotes possibly being necessarry, I went through the whole file and manually deleted every single extra double quote.  After doing that, the TNT shipping label rendered correctly in the browser with all appropriate barcodes and images.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much, David! I was beating my head against the wall with this problem.  Apparently saving a document with the Open and Write methods can sometimes input extra double quotes, which makes the document render improperly in a web browser.  Thanks again, dude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Excel writing VBA code

1. Write the "string" out to a cell - Range("G1") = "string"
2. Put the following in your VBA code

   Cells.Replace What:="""""", Replacement:="""", LookAt:=xlPart, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False
3. Read the "string" back into a variable - XXX = Range("G1")
4. Debug.Print the variable and you'll see the double quotes are gone. I don't know why it works ... don't much care ... but it does. Found it when I was trying to put a json string together out of vba.

(It's actually output from Excel's record a macro ... I know I know shaaammmeee. I'm ok ... you'll be back)

Answer (score 0):

For similar problem I used code:

```
For i = 0 To lastArrayIndex
    thisString = columnsDataInThisLine(i)
    theFirstStringSymbol = Left(thisString, 1)
    If theFirstStringSymbol = """" Then
        'Replace double double quotes in the string beginning and _
        'the end into single double quotes
        thisString = Mid(thisString, 2, Len(thisString) - 2) 
    End If
    columnsDataInThisLine(i) = thisString
Next i
```

here is link to my problem [Replace 2 double quotes into 1 double quote during data load from csv file in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910422/replace-2-double-quotes-into-1-double-quote-during-data-load-from-csv-file-in-vb/47911188#47911188)