# Replace 2 double quotes into 1 double quote during data load from csv file in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, double-quotes

I loaded line from csv file into array (Open dataFilePath For Input As #1 and so on…). Loaded in array data are in 2 double quotes. Examples: “””” (empty string) , “”myText””, “”75823””. Problem is that later in the code program can’t correctly detect empty array element or other data. I found method how to replace 2 double quotes in the beginning of string and at the end of the string into 1 double quote:

```
For i = 0 To lastArrayIndex
    thisString = columnsDataInThisLine(i)
    theFirstStringSymbol = Left(thisString, 1)
    If theFirstStringSymbol = """" Then
        'Replace double double quotes in the string beginning and _
        'the end into single double quotes
        thisString = Mid(thisString, 2, Len(thisString) - 2) 
    End If
    columnsDataInThisLine(i) = thisString
Next i
```

after this code I got what I need -  Examples: “” (empty string) , “myText”, “75823”, but maybe I missed something during data load from csv file (encoding or something else). Maybe it is simpler way to remove this 2 double quotes at the beginning and at the end of loaded into array strings during csv file reading?

Comment: Slight off-topic; in VBA you can use the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  It's easier and more powerful than the old `Open x For Input AS #1`.  Assuming you have a line that looks a little like this `Split(CurrentLine, ",")` you could replace with: `Split(Replace(CurrentLine, """", ""), ",")`.  Watch out.  Quotes can be used to override commas.  In this example there are only two columns: `"Column one, which contains a comma", "Column two"`.

Comment: do not forget, you have to escape double quotes ... `a = """"` and `b = """"""` ... a is `"` ... b is `""`

Comment: According destination-data comment: In data which I load are lot of commas inside quotes. I overcome this problem with Regex.Pattern = """[^""]*""|[^,]*"  , because with split function I didn't find solution. Maybe for FileSystemObject is some parameters or in VBA library similarly as in .NET is something like TextFieldParser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This double quotes are language specific. If these are the only characters that you would like to avoid and you do not have any other "strange" characters, then you can loop through the characters of your cells in Excel and check whether they are non-standard (e.g. not part of the first 128 ASCII chars):

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim stringToEdit    As String
    Dim cnt             As Long
    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim newWord         As String

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A2")
        newWord = vbNullString
        For cnt = 1 To Len(myCell)
            Debug.Print Asc(Mid(myCell, cnt, 1))
            If Asc(Mid(myCell, cnt, 1)) >= 127 Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                newWord = newWord & Mid(myCell, cnt, 1)
            End If
        Next cnt
        myCell = newWord
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Thus, imagine that you have input like this:

[image]

It would realize, that the quotes are a bit strange and should not be included in the original text, because they are not part of the first 128 units in the ASCII table.

After running the code you would get an empty cell and 75823.

Comment: I load data not from Excel sheet but from csv file directly into arrays through 
 code Open dataFilePath For Input As #1 and so on… . I don't want at this code block have nothing  related with Excel workbooks sheets, because it depending on user Excel settings can corrupt important data (can lost 0 from the begging of  string - example post codes, phone numbers, can lost some symbols).